# How to forward the form-based SAML SSO redirect in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, redirect, single-sign-on

I'm trying to solve a problem with SAML SSO POST binding where the protected Web application contains Ajax script. After the intial authentication, which is handled by browser, the Web application's Ajax code starts to retrieve data from the server without problem. However, when the security session times out, the service provider (SP) resend the SAMLRequest to the identity provider (IdP) via SAML SSO POST, which is implemented using a form with auto submit. Since this response has code 200, the form with the SAMLRequest ends up in Ajax callback and Ajax callback is not expecting it and does not now to handle it.

My question is:

1. Is there a way for Ajax callback code to tell browser that it would not like to handle this response and ask the browser to handle it in its normal way?
2. If not, how can I mimic the browser's behavior, which is to simply submit the already-filled form automatically?

Thanks,
Gang

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is one that I came across in working with WIF and WS-Federation integration to an SSO IdP where the web application heavily utilizes AJAX. Within the Microsoft Identity Model SAML tokens are processed and FedAuth cookies are created that manage the session timeout values. The actual maximum session lifetime is calculated as the clock skew plus the SAML assertion lifetime, which in most cases is 10 minutes.  When the maximum session lifetime expires, WIF based on the Microsoft Identity Model (on behalf of the SP web application), will re-negotiate a new SAML token via the WS-FED passive browser profile.  In cases where the web browser action does not involve a full form post (e.g. AJAX), the request will fail to be processed. It looks as if the application hangs, but in reality it is still active, the user would need to click the browser refresh and processing would continue.

The best solution I have implemented, is to overload the Microsoft Identity Model DLL with a custom DLL to calculate the maximum session timeout to something longer than SAML assertion plus clock skew.  The solution was to have a value in the web.config that represented the maximum session timeout (e.g. 4 hours), thus avoiding the AJAX issue when FedAuth cookies expired.

Another variation is the desired behavior is to frequently get SAML assertions from the SSO IdP.  This requires some sliding logic in a custom DLL to overload the Microsoft Identity Model DLL.